# Custom ArrayAdapter getView Not Being Called--Why Not?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I used this same pattern in another Activity class and it works perfectly.  But in this class (also an Activity) the getView is *never* called.  I confirmed that there are 9 item in the adapter by logging the fbFriendMatchAdapter.getCount().  I've tried changing the data source to a String[] variable but this had no impact on the (lack of) getView.

I would appreciate any suggestions!  I've already researched SO thoroughly. There are a variety of flavors of this question but none have solved my issue.  That's why I'm posting a new question.

```
//Here is the ArrayList data source definition.
//It is loaded using a for loop with 9 values.
private List<String> fbFriendMatchAdapter=new ArrayList<String>();


// Here is the Custom Array Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> fbFriendMatchAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.row_left, R.id.ListViewName, fbFriendPotentialMatchArrayList) { 

    @Override
    public View getView(final int dialogPosition, View convertView, ViewGroup listParent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View fbFriendMatchDialogViewRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_left, listParent, false); 
        Log.d(BBTAG, String.format("BBSetup getView[%s] name=%s", dialogPosition, buddyDisplayName ));

        return fbFriendMatchDialogViewRow;
    }  // [END getView]

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return fbFriendPotentialMatchArrayList.get(position);
    }

};

//Here is the dialog that includes the ArrayAdapter:
AlertDialog fbFriendsMatchDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.PetesSpinnerReplacement))
        .setTitle("Select Correct Facebook Friend")  //FYI overridden by custom title
        .setAdapter(fbFriendMatchAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedFBFriend) {
                buddyFBUIDs[buddyNumber] = fbFriendUIDsList.get(selectedFBFriend);  
            }
        })
        .setMessage("No matches found")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Set as Facebook Friend", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int iFriend) {
                 dialog.dismiss();
             } 
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Friend Not Listed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                buddyFBUIDs[buddyNumber] = "n/a";  //record lack of FB uid
            } 
        })  
        .create();  //build dialog
fbFriendsMatchDialog.show();  // now show dialog
```

Comment: can you post your getCount method ?

Comment: To be sure I was getting the correct count I did not override getCount (i.e., I am using the default method).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would advise against trying to inline an `ArrayAdapter` subclass for this, as I believe `ArrayAdapter` makes some assumptions about the structure of your layout and data that may be throwing you off. Writing your own custom adapter is so dead simple that I would almost recommend *never* using `ArrayAdapter` (except maybe for the simplest of use cases). Just subclass `BaseAdapter` and the four required methods, and use that. Something like this:

```
private class MatchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<String> mItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MatchAdapter (Context c, List<String> items) {
        mItems = items;

        //Cache a reference to avoid looking it up on every getView() call
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount () {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId (int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem (int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //If there's no recycled view, inflate one and tag each of the views
        //you'll want to modify later
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate (R.layout.row_left, parent, false);

            //This assumes layout/row_left.xml includes a TextView with an id of "textview"
            convertView.setTag (R.id.textview, convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview));
        }

        //Retrieve the tagged view, get the item for that position, and
        //update the text
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.getTag(R.id.textview);
        String textItem = (String) getItem(position);
        textView.setText(textItem);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that looks appetizing!  I will give it a try right now.  I also liked your idea to cache the layout inflator.  Good tip.

Comment: bad news--the MatchAdapter had no effect on the problem.  getView is still not being called.  FYI I copy/pasted your class and revised the id names.  Then I instantiated the adapter as `MatchAdapter fbFriendMatchAdapter = new MatchAdapter(this, fbFriendPotentialMatchArrayList);`.  Do you have you any other insights/ideas?

Comment: I also should note that there's also a ListView on this layout with its own independent ArrayAdapter.  It sits underneath the dialog when the dialog is displayed.  Could that be interfering with the MatchAdapter?  If so, is there a way to deal with it?

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since it's clear you put some effort into customizing the answer to my question.  However, as it turns out, the ArrayAdapter had nothing to do with the actual problem and is 100% working.  The problem, which I am *extremely* annoyed about (after chasing for half a day), is the .setMessage in the AlertDialog.  It causes the item list not to be displayed.  After removing the setMessage everything now works.